# Button on card prevent new tab link from launching

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a card component that has a green button on the top right, an image and text below it, I want to be able to click on anywhere on the card and for it to redirect to the url in the code; however if the green button is clicked, it should do nothing and not open the url. In the code below it doesn't do that, instead it always opens the url. I used href as it allows the left click on mouse to open in the same page, but the middle click to open a new tab while remaining in the same page which is very important.

Here is a link to a codeSandBox having the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-chy0d?file=/demo.js

Code:

```
export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <a href="sdfs">
        <CardActionArea style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
          <div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              color: "white",
              top: 8,
              right: 8
            }}
          >
            <Button
              style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}
              onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
              size="small"
              color="primary"
            >
              BUTTON
            </Button>
          </div>

          <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image="https://media.tarkett-image.com/large/TH_25121916_25131916_25126916_25136916_001.jpg"
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              jnikn
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              ijneodsk ipknv onfp o nf onopndsfc on pnojnc olpnoinoi hbib iubn
              iujno nouno oijipj onoin ioio
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </a>
    </Card>
  );
```

Comment: Hey John check here [media](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#media) button kept outside of CardActionArea so you will do same. also Instead of adding parent `<a>` tag use `<CardActionArea component={"a"}` ....

Comment: That won't work because I want the whole card to be clickable, if the buttons are placed outside, that part of the card is not clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    position: "relative"
  },
  media: {
    height: 140
    // marginTop: 50
  }
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <Button
              style={{ zIndex:'1000',
              position: "absolute",
              top: 8,
              right: 8,background: "green", color: "white",width:'70px',height:'30px' }}
              onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
              size="small"
              color="primary"
            >
              BUTTON
            </Button>
      <a href="sdfs">
        <CardActionArea style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>

          <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image="https://media.tarkett-image.com/large/TH_25121916_25131916_25126916_25136916_001.jpg"
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              jnikn
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              ijneodsk ipknv onfp o nf onopndsfc on pnojnc olpnoinoi hbib iubn
              iujno nouno oijipj onoin ioio
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </a>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why adding the zIndex:'1000' makes this work @Dean

Comment: For layer order. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.